# Why does CloudKit SwiftUI save data Xcode build to device but not from TestFlight version?

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit

I am finishing a SwiftUI app in Xcode 12.5.1 that saves data to CloudKit. The basic process is:

1. Create new Project
2. Create new Tasks

Then you can edit or delete the projects and tasks. When I do this by building to my iPhone 12 from Xcode the entire CRUD process works fine for Projects and Tasks and saves to CloudKit.

However, when I upload the app to TestFlight everything works fine except creating new Tasks. I can create Projects and edit and delete existing Tasks but cannot create new Tasks in the TestFlight version.

In CloudKit I have deployed Schema changes from Development to Production and confirmed that all the fields are showing up. When I try and create a new Task from the TestFlight version it does not show up in CloudKit. I have waited, giving it plenty of time. I have refreshed the display and still the record is not created. Then when I close out the app and open it again, the Task is gone from the app. The app does not crash or display errors and I get no errors in CloudKit.

Here is the code creating the CloudKit container

```
init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: DataController.coreDataModelName)
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "dev/null")
        }
        
        container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
            
            self.container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
      
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Fatal error loading store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } 
    }
```

Here is the code for creating a new task:

```
Button(action: {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                    let newTask = Task(context: dataController.managedObjectContext)
                    newTask.creationDate = Date()
                    newTask.name = self.name
                    newTask.notes = self.note
                    newTask.isComplete = false
                    newTask.project = project
                    newTask.id = UUID()
                    dataController.save()
                }
                
                showNewTaskModal = false
            })
```

Function for saving data (updated):

```
func save() {
    if container.viewContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try container.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
} //: SAVE
```

Any help in sorting this out will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `?` in `try?`, put it in a `do try catch` and use `print(error)` in the `catch`. Maybe you'll get a message

Comment: @loremipsum I'll give that try. Thank you.

Comment: @loremipsum I added the do try catch block. No errors were presented when building to the simulator or the device. I uploaded to TestFlight and Tasks still do not save. Appears to be a deeper issue.

Comment: Is this your actual code? How do you look for errors in test flight? You should have an alert of some kind. I’m assuming this is an oversimplified version since it doesn’t have any way to post the errors

Comment: This is my actual code. I just updated the Save() function in the code above. I don't have a way to test for errors in TestFlight. I am just checking CloudKit to see if new Tasks are saved there.

Comment: Updating the save doesn’t do anything then. You need to be able to get the error code. It is good practice to let your user know there has been an error. You should be posting an error via alert or some kind of notification when an error occurs. If not they are left like you are now. You just don’t know. That fatal error in your persistence container should be replaced by an elegant procedure to tell the user why there is an error and what to do. That can be triggered by the user running out of storage space and your app will just crash. Over and over again for no reason in the users view.

Comment: https://www.grantgrueninger.com/2020/01/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer-in-production/